# Can a single textView display two different texts from two different string resources?

Tags: java, android, textview, radio-button

I want to use the same layout with `TextView`s but change the text in the `TextView`s alternately when someone clicks a `RadioButton` on/off. While the RadioButton were programmatically in mainactivity and transferred the boolean value through an intent; using the boolean value,  I'm planning to use an if/else statement for the on/off text changes programmatically in activity. I put the texts in resources `string.xml .

This is my intent getting the value (true/false) from main activity.

```js
boolean value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("s",false);
```

And here directly I use the value in my second activity, but it seem did not work. no text display on my second layout.

```js
if (!value) {
            room_a.setText(getString(R.string.marvelous));
            room_b.setText(getString(R.string.ugly));
            room_c.setText(getString(R.string.undecided));
        }
        else if(value==false){
            return;
        }
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: if you do an if/else, you can just set the text to one thing inside of if, and another thing inside else. unless i am mistaken what your question is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that. Refer the following code

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(newCompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   if(isChecked)

      textview.setText(getString(R.string.string1));
   else

      textview.setText(getString(R.string.string2));

   }
});
```

Comment: Correct Answer @Yashaswi

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your can listen to changes of a radio button and then just call setText(R.string.mystring) on the text view.  Depending on the state of the radio button you can set different texts.